# error compiling code - 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

Tags: c

I'm compiling gvmlib with make and this is showing the following error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode.

I used gcc in the code with the --std=c99 and --std=gnu99 option in the code and **fatal error** appears: glib.h file or directory not found

I installed glib 2.0 and it was working normally

follow the part of the code that is giving error

```
static element_t find_child(element_t element, const gchar *name)
{
      for (xmlNode *node = element->children; node; node = node->next)
          if (xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *)name) == 0)
              return node;
      return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Is this c code? Then don't tag it with c++.

Comment: You have stated two errors here. So which one are you really asking about? For the first problem you have already found the solution. For the second problem you have not given enough information.

Comment: @kaylum: The "fix" for the first is what caused the second.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler option to enable C99 (without changing anything else) is not `--std=c99`, it is `--std=gnu99`.

If you use `--std=c99` you both enable C99 and also disable GNU extensions that were turned on by the default setting (which is `--std=gnu89`).

Of course by now you may want to use `--std=gnu11` or `--std=gnu18`.

Comment: yes, i had already tried '--std=gnu99' and glib.h file or directory not found appears

Comment: @Ben or even use gnu18

Comment: @Fredrik: agreed